# RFE Termination Using RMSE with AutoFSelector

Tags: mlr3

To mimic how caret performs RFE and select features that produce the lowest RMSE, it was suggested to use the archive.

I am using AutoFSelector and nested resampling with the following code:

```
ARMSS<-read.csv("Index ARMSS Proteomics Final.csv", row.names=1)

set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer")

task = as_task_regr(ARMSS, target = "Index.ARMSS")

learner = lrn("regr.ranger", importance = "impurity")

set_threads(learner, n = 8)

resampling_inner = rsmp("cv", folds = 7)
measure = msr("regr.rmse")
terminator = trm("none")

at = AutoFSelector$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling_inner,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = terminator,
  fselect = fs("rfe", n_features = 1, feature_fraction = 0.5, recursive = FALSE),
  store_models = TRUE)

resampling_outer = rsmp("repeated_cv", folds = 10, repeats = 10)

rr = resample(task, at, resampling_outer, store_models = TRUE)
```

Should I use the extract_inner_fselect_archives() command to identify each iteration with the smallest RMSE and the features that were selected then rereun the code above with the n_features argument changed? How do I reconcile differences across iterations in the number of features and/or the features selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nested resampling is a statistical procedure to estimate the predictive performance of the model trained on the full dataset, it is not a procedure to select optimal hyperparameters. Nested resampling produces many hyperparameter configurations which should not be used to construct a final model.

mlr3book [Chapter 4 - Optimization](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#sec-nested-resampling).

The same is true for feature selection. You don't select a feature set with nested resampling. You estimate the performance of the final model.

> it was suggested to use the archive

Without nested resampling, you just call `instance$result` or `at$fselect_result` to get the feature subset with the lowest rmse.

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped and I've now adjusted my approach.